# Tomcat 7 URL rewrite from other domain

Tags: tomcat, rewrite, tls

On a tomcat 7 server, we've configured a https connector, the TLS certificate is valid for an URL like www.example.com . Now we want to change the A record of one of our subdomains (like foo.bar.com) to point to the tomcat server.

How can I rewrite/process incoming requests from foo.bar.com to use https://www.example.com in order to prevent users from getting certificate errors shown in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Stand up an Apache server (or virtual host) at foo.bar.com, and have it proxy connections to www.example.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.bar.com
  ProxyPass / https://www.example.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But this won't completely work if the HTML returned from www.example.com includes links with absolute references to URLs starting with www.example.com.  In that case you'll need to use something like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) to rewrite the links within the content.

Comment: One of our goals is to get rid of foo.bar.com's VM, therefore a solution which could be realized on www.example.com's VM, ideally within Tomcat's scope, would be preferred. Any hints?

Comment: The above can run on Tomcat's VM, but it does assume Apache listening on port 80.